# How can a vector be used in this way?

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector

Can someone explain this code please? how is it that the function bar accepts a reference to the first element of the vector?

```
jintArray arry;
std::vector<int> foo = GetIntegerArray(env, arry);
bar(&foo[0])
```

where the protoytpe of bar is

```
bar(int* array)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is valid as long as the template type isn't `bool`. The C++ vector type specifies that the vector elements are consecutive in memory like that so that you can do exactly this.

The reason why it doesn't work with `bool` is due to template specialization. Where the bools are compressed down to a bitfield.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_%28C%2B%2B%29#vector.3Cbool.3E_specialization

Answer (score 3):

> how is it that the function bar accepts a reference to the first element of the vector?

This seems to be the source of the confusion. The expression `&foo[0]` is not a reference to the first element, but rather a pointer. `operator[]` is overloaded in the `vector` class to obtain a reference (or const-reference), and applying `&` will obtain the address of the object.

Comment: @pingu: I always wonder how is it that answers get accepted... is the original question you had answered by the accepted answer? Your question as I understand it is *why does `bar` accept the reference `&foo[0]`?*, and the accepted answer only states that the code is valid...

Comment: It was the line "vector elements are consecutive in memory" that answered my question.

Comment: @pingu: That is exactly my point: you wanted to know something but asked a different thing. You wanted to know why you can pass the address of the first element to a function that requires a pointer to a dynamically allocated array, but you actually asked why was it allowed to pass a *reference* to a function that requires a pointer (no mention to the pointer being interpreted as an array of elements inside `bar`). My point is that if that is the accepted answer, then the question is quite bad and should be reviewed, as there is no clear connexion from the question to the answer.

Comment: When I read the question, it was pretty clear (to me) what the OP was trying to do and what he/she wanted to know. But I can see how it can be read in more than one way.

Comment: Sometimes when you don't understand something, it is not always easy to write completely concise questions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Just make sure the vector is not empty, or `&foo[0]` would be an error. C++11 introduced the `std::vector<T>::data()` function that does not have this problem.

Also, returning a vector by value is usually not a good idea. You might want to use an output iterator or a vector reference parameter in `GetIntegerArray`, so you would call it like this:

```
std::vector<int> foo;
GetIntegerArray(env, arry, back_inserter(foo));
```

or

```
std::vector<int> foo;
GetIntegerArray(env, arry, foo);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `std::vector<int>`, it is guaranteed that all the element are created in contiguous memory. As such, when you write `&v[0]` it returns the pointer to the first element, and from this you can go the next element by writing `&v[0]+1`, and so on.

By the way, if you want to traverse through all elements or a section of elements, then a better interface for `bar` would be this:

```
void bar(int *begin, int *end)
{
     for ( ; begin != end; ++begin)
     {
         //code
     }    
}
```

So you can call like this:

```
bar(&foo[0], &foo[0] + foo.size());//process all elements
bar(&foo[0], &foo[0] + foo.size()/2);//process first half elements
bar(&foo[0], &foo[0] + N); //process first N elements(assumingN <=foo.size())
bar(&foo[0]+foo.size()/2, &foo[0]+foo.size());//process second half elements
```

Comment: Many thanks, this could have been accepted answer but @Mysticial was first.

Comment: @pingu: So you accept answer, based on who posts first? Or who posts better? :P

Comment: All else being the same, I accept on who answered first, that's fair isn't it?